# What is the terminology of the collection of all possible combinations of the element of a set?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, combinations

Let me explain my question better:

Suppose I have a set $(1,2,3)$. Clearly, I have 6 ways to choose some elements from it:
$$
(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)
$$
and I can make a collection to collection those new elements by
$$
\mathcal A= \{(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}
$$
My question:
what is the name, or the terminology of collection $\mathcal A$? Is there a common symbol of it? I tried to search over Wiki but find nothing...The only thing I know is that $C(3,2)$ denotes how many ways we could choose 2 elements from 3 elements. but it is not what I want. I want to denote the actually collections.

Comment: If $S$ is a set then the Power Set (often written as $2^S$) is the set of subsets of $S$.  Note that this includes the empty set and the whole set $S$ itself, hence isn't exactly the same as your collection.

Comment: I see I see. I totally forgot the power set. I can use it. Thank you! @lulu

Comment: But your example is not the power set. The power set here has $2^3$ elements. Hence the notation in @lulu's Comment. You have forgotten the null set and the whole space S.